# How to integrate Angular 4 into Rails Application and what is actual folder structure of Angular within Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, typescript

Is there any the proper document for angular to integrating into Rails Application.

What will be folder structure?

#### As per angular 4 doc: https://angular.io/styleguide

```
--Rails App Root
|-- app
|-- bin
|-- src --> Angular Folder
|-- config
|-- db
|-- lib
...
...
```

#### As per many blogs

in app -> assets folder?

```
--Rails App root
|-- app
 |-- assets
  |-- src --> Angular Folder
..
..
```

Which one is preferred?

Is there any rules/path/structure for Angular within Rails App.

Could anyone give some example?

Answer (score 1):

When I use any JS Framework with Rails, I create a folder for each. Assuming you use the Rails side as your API I would structure the folders as so.

```
Root Directory (App Name)
--Rails (API)
--Angular (Frontend)
```

Then you can run your Rails Generates, Rakes and whatever commands you wish in their correlating parent folder. I've found that this keeps all the code organized.

Here is a demo that will show you how to wire up your Rails API to talk to your Angular front-end.

https://www.angularonrails.com/getting-started-with-angular-and-rails/

Hope this helps!

Comment: in that url they are using anjular within rails folder `app/assets/javascripts/angular`

Comment: One more clarification, If there are 2 different projects with different technology how can we deploy?

Comment: @Aravin I am not super familiar with Angular 4, BUT every JS framework I have used, works by using a "listener". The listener waits for the Rails API to respond after a request has been sent and acts accordingly.